# Person who is decent on a language

Tags: translation

What do you call a person who is good but not very good on a language . A person who is decent on a language.

For instance can I say "ich bin anständig auf die Deutsche sprache"  is this right. I am not sure about this can someone correct me if the sentence wrong and give a correct answer

Comment: You could use "einigermaßen" ("somewhat", "reasonably", "to some degree"), as in "Ich spreche einigermaßen Deutsch".

Comment: My question was a correct adjective for a person who has a mediocre skills  on a language. But thanks anyway for your try to help Henning Kockerbeck

Comment: What's wrong with a simple "gut" then?

Comment: I have also thought about that but "gut"  sounds little bit unfit for "mediocre"

Comment: Not to me. For instance in a cv, you could have levels: verhandlungssicher/sehr gut/gut/Grundkenntnisse. So it would go somewhere between basic knowledge and very good. "Verhandlungssicher", would be near native level. Perhaps you need to be a bit more specific about the actual level, because "good but not very good" could mean a lot of things.

Comment: you have answered the mate. Thanks  user1583209 I appreciate that mate.

Comment: Why don't you just translate it directly: "Ich spreche ganz vernünftig Deutsch"? Regarding your question: Your sentence has to be "Ich spreche die deutsche Sprache ganz anständig". Both your preposition and your word order are incorrect. The verb "sein" seems awkward in this specific context to me so I used "sprechen" instead.

Comment: This an answer to my question pbx thanks for the answer and thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @pbx: Post this as answer, and I will upvote...

Comment: @TorstenLink Thanks for your suggestion. I did so and extended the answer a bit more in order not to feel guilty for such a short and halfhearted answer ;-)

Answer (score 4):

*Off-topic:* On specific demand I now re-post my former comment as a complete answer. I hesitated to do so because it at first seemed a bit half-baked to me. I am going to extend the initial comment to justify the type `anwer` instead of `comment` a bit more.

---

**Personal suggestion**

Why don't you just translate your question directly as in

> Ich spreche ganz vernünftig Deutsch

for example? There is no specific construction or adjective that is sine qua non for what you want to express in the German language. Instead there are many possibilities to say what you want to say. I gave one example, [Artery](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/33497/24484) gave two others with constructions based on "einigermaßen" or "passabel". One could think of some more as in

> Ich spreche (sehr) brauchbar Deutsch.
>
> Ich bin in der deutschen Sprache relativ sicher.
>
> Ich kann recht gut Deutsch sprechen.

which are not direct translations of your sentence but paraphrased versions.

---

**Your suggestion**

Regarding your proposal: Your sentence has to be

> Ich spreche die deutsche Sprache ganz anständig.

Both your preposition and your word order are incorrect. The verb "sein" seems awkward in this specific context to me so I used "sprechen" instead.

---

**Nice to know**

If you try to find a version for your official CV to express that you can speak German quite well: Refrain from using the above translations and refer to your exact language level via [CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I wouldn't say it this way.

In my opinion a good one would be:

> "Ich spreche passabel Deutsch"

or

> "Ich spreche einigermaßen (gut) Deutsch"

Without the "gut" it's more colloquial.
I think in this case

> "passabel"

would be a good translation for "decent". It means, that your german is "okay", neither very good nor bad ;)

Your sentence has a couple of mistakes in it:

> "auf die Deutsche sprache"

is incorrect, you would rather say

> "in der deutschen Sprachen"

If I stick to your base-sentence I would say:

> "Ich bin passabel in der deutschen Sprache"

But no native speaker would say that at all :D

Furthermore you have some typos in it. If you start a sentence, you always start with an upper case letter. Furthermore "deutsche" is written in lower case, because it is an adjective. "Sprache" on the other hand is written in upper case, too, because its a noun.

Comment: Mistakes in a question that are not related to the topic actually being asked should rather be edited. To state why something is wrong, you would leave a comment under the question. You only have 20 rep to go before you can comment everywhere; keep it up ;)

Comment: Thanks for this advices, I am pretty new to this sub-"exchange" :D